# Is there a way to edit a comment after you have refreshed the question page?

Tags: support, edits, comments

I have something to add to one of my comments that I commented earlier today and when I refreshed the page the edit option diapered so I was wondering if there is a way to edit them after I refreshed the page?

Comment: [Read How to Comments Work on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Comment: Note that refreshing the page does not have any effect on the `edit` button. The button vanishes 5 minutes after you have posted the comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. Comment edits are intended for things like fixing typos. You only have a 5 minute window in which to edit, and the timer stops altogether when you navigate away from the page. It is hard to spot a typo when you're on another page.

[Comments are considered to be second class citizens here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) You are strongly encouraged to avoid posting comments. If you have an answer to a question, post an answer, not a comment. If you have something to add to your question, edit it into the body of the question itself. Don't just leave it as an easily-missed comment.

Looking at your profile, I see that you recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705704/what-is-the-difference-between-javafx-desktop-and-javafx-mobile). Vertex asked you a question, and you replied to him in a comment. That works, but it is not ideal. You should have edited your question to incorporate that information into the question itself. That way, other people who come across your question will not have to read all of the comments just to get all the important details. Posting three different comments to your question (especially one right after another) is *highly* unusual, and almost always suggests that you should be editing instead.

Either that, or it suggests that your question is insufficiently specific. It looks to me like that's the case in this particular example. You are supposed to ask about *specific, practical programming problems* on Stack Overflow. Your question asks for someone to explain to you the similarities and differences between JavaFX Desktop and Mobile. That's not the kind of thing that can be answered on this website. It is far too broad. Do you really think someone is going to be able to post an exhaustive list of similarities and differences?